# Change font-size of embedded tweet generated using factory function

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

According to twitter's current docs you can set css styles to the blockquote you render your tweet in to adjust the final result:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/css

Unfortunately this does not work if the blockquote is generated dynamically. I'm using Backbone.js to render a view with a tagName set to blockquote and a class name of .twitter-tweet. In my stylesheets i have .twitter-tweet { font-size: 20px } but the tweet still renders at 10px ( the body font-size )

Any clue how I can change the embedded tweet's font-size? ( it's in an iframe btw )

Comment: you can use javascript to call the url and render the html response on your page not using an iframe.  Then you have control over the styles, otherwise you have no control

Comment: @ScottSelby what url? the tweet url? cause that doesn't work as CORS stops this.

Comment: you can do cross domain requests with jsonp , their docs say if you add an optional paramater of 'callback' then the response will come as jsonp

Comment: oh? do you have a link to that in the docs? i must have missed it. thx!

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: that endpoint is unfortunately rate limited

Comment: do it server side then , the is really the way it should be done

Comment: I know I can rate limit and cache the tweet on our end and parse the tweet with appropriate links, but if twitter does half the work and the only thing i want to do is change the font size, I'm 99% there.

Answer (score 0):

I am recommending a simple PHP RSS/DOM pharser, like these:
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - Link element in RSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889659/php-simple-html-dom-parser-link-element-in-rss#24889840)
or
http://simplepie.org/

Comment: What does parsing the tweet going to do? Also I don't want to deal with twitter's rate limiting.

Comment: You can select those DOM elements what do you really need and print them as you wish. The parser can be a PHP file on your server, loaded dínamically with javascript/jQuery/Ajax

Comment: Right but the problem is that I need the tweet to be fresh and Twitter rate limits updating tweet content. We would hit that rate limit quickly.